# Getting the amount of a plan using stripe API in django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have the following class bassed view which handles get / post between my django application and stripe API:

```
class StripeApi(View):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html',
                      {
                          'stripe_pub_key': settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
                      })

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        charge = stripe.Customer.create(
            source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
            email=request.POST['stripeEmail'],
            plan=request.POST['plan'],
            description='Charge for {}'.format(request.POST.get("stripeEmail", "")),
        )

        paym = stripe.Charge.retrieve(
            source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
            amount=request.POST.get("amount", "")
        )

        return render(request, 'stripe.html',
                      {
                          'charge_id': charge.id,
                          'created': charge.created,
                          'email': request.POST['stripeEmail'],
                          'plan': request.POST['plan'],
                          'amount': request.POST.get("amount", "")
                      })
```

And the following HTML that sends the necessary parameters:

```
<form action="stripe/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="test12months" id="plan" name="plan">
    <input type="hidden" value="stripeEmail" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail">
    <input type="hidden" value="amount" id="amount" name="amount">
    <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_secret"
            data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
            data-name="12 Months"
            data-description="12 Months Subscription (19.99$ per year)"
            data-amount= "1999"
            data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

The problem is that I get the following error when I am trying to add the `amount`:

`Exception Value: retrieve() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` when I add the `amount`.

Can somebody help me figure how can I retrieve the amount of a specific created plan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the amount of a plan, you need to issue a [plan retrieval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#retrieve_plan) call:

```
plan = stripe.Plan.retrieve(request.POST['plan'])
amount = plan.amount
```

Your [charge retrieval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#retrieve_charge) call is invalid: to retrieve a charge, you need to pass its ID, which in this case you don't have because you didn't directly create the charge -- rather, you created a [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#subscription_object), and Stripe automatically created a charge for you.